# Proper model defination in django for a widget manager

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called `widgetManager` and 2 widget models called `emailWidget` and `TextWidget`. Now a single instance of widgetManager can have multiple instances of emailWidget and TextWidget. How can this be achieved with the following in mind

1. Till now i only have two but there can be more in future
2. The order of widget is very important

I have tried with adding two many-many relations in widgetManager but that seems impractical and not the best way to go around because if first condition.

What i have in mind is maybe i can somehow make a base widget class and extend all the widgets from that class but i am not sure about that. Would be super helpful if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your description correctly, you want a relationship where there can be many emailWidget or TextWidget for one instance of widgetManager.

What you can do in this case is add a ForeignKey field for widgetManager to emailWidget and TextWidget. This way, you can have many instances of the widgets while they refer to the same manager.

I think you may have confused inheritance with model relationships when you said you want to extend widgets from a base class. Perhaps I'm wrong?

Not sure what you mean't about order of the widget being important either..